# Dialog in android

Tags: android

I have created a dialog box in android . This dialog has an `EditText` view and an `Ok`, `Cancel` button. I want to know how can i manage click events in my dialog.

```
    final Dialog d= new Dialog(MyClass.this);
    Window window= d.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
    window.setTitle("Add Item");
    window.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
```

I have create an XML layout file for dialog which is :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
 <Button android:text="Add" android:id="@+id/dialogAddBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 <Button android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/dialogCancelBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

For managing Click events on `Ok` button, I have written this listener

```
Button okBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogAddBtn);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                  myEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
```

But Click event is not working. Please suggest me some solutions.....

Answer (score 1):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  input.setText("");
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

  }
});

alert.show();
```